# Symfony 5, Doctrine queryBuilder OneToMany Relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I need help with Symfony 5, Doctrine queryBuilder. I need to find some item that OneToMany relation only have files from a selected file group.

```
Entity structure:
    Documents.php:
       Id
       Name: (string)
       FILES: (OneToMany DocumentsFiles.php)
    DocumentsFiles.php: 
            Id
            File: (OneToOne)
            FileGroup: (ManyToOne DocumentsFilesGroup.php)
            Documents: (ManyToOne Documents.php)
    DocumentsFilesGroup.php:
            Id
            Name: (string)
            ShortName: (string)
            Files: (OneToMany DocumentsFiles.php)

Database:
    Document
        ID, NAME, FILES (OneToMany)
        1, SomeName, [{1, File, 1},{2, File1, 1},{3, File2, 1},{4, File3, 2}],
        2, SomeName1, [{5, File4, 1},{6, File5, 1}]
        3, SomeName2, [{12, File11, 2}]
        4, SomeName3, [{13, File12, 1}]
        5, SomeName4, [{16, File15, 2}]
    DocumentsFileGroups
        Id, Name, ShortName
        1, Temporary, tmp
        2, Final, final
For example:
    I need document with temporary files only.
    Result:  
        2, SomeName1, [{5, File4, 1},{6, File5, 1}]
        4, SomeName3, [{13, File12, 1}]

In DocumentRepository i have query:
$query->addSelect('nodeFiles')->leftJoin('node.files', 'nodeFiles')->leftJoin(\App\Entity\DocumentsFiles::class, 'nodeExt', Expr\Join::WITH, 'nodeExt.fileGroup IN (:documentsFileGroup) AND nodeExt.fileGroup NOT IN (:documentsNotFileGroup)')
                                        ->setParameter('documentsFileGroup', 1)
                                        ->setParameter('documentsNotFileGroup', 2);
But in results i have:
  (wrong) 1, SomeName, [{1, File, 1},{2, File1, 1},{3, File2, 1},{4, File3, 2}],
  2, SomeName1, [{5, File4, 1},{6, File5, 1}]
  4, SomeName3, [{13, File12, 1}]
```

Anyone have an idea or a clue?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `innerJoin` instead of `leftJoin` DocumentsFiles oe even better put filter condition into `where()`, because You don't need to join `DocumentFiles` twice. It could look like this:

```
$query->addSelect('nodeFiles')
    ->innerJoin('node.files', 'nodeFiles')
    ->where($query->expr()->eq('nodeFiles.fileGroup', ':documentsFileGroup'))
    ->andWhere($query->expr()->neq('nodeExt.fileGroup', ':documentsNotFileGroup'))
    ->setParameter('documentsFileGroup', 1)
    ->setParameter('documentsNotFileGroup', 2);
```